# adding tab dropdown on slide up and down div on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-ui

[image: slide-down div on click]

This drop down div is view after click packages and i want to add when select choose your destination change the icon set. i tried but when click drop down item on list main div slide up...

my jquery code is below

//SLIDE UP AND DOWN FUNCTION

```
$('li.dropdown-packages a').on('click', function(e){
             e.preventDefault();
             e.stopPropagation();

var $packages = $('.custom-packages');

        if($packages.is(":visible")){
            $packages.slideUp(350);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('li.dropdown-packages').removeClass('dwn-arrow');
            }, 800);
        }
        if($packages.is(":hidden")){
            $packages.slideDown(350);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('li.dropdown-packages').addClass('dwn-arrow');
            },800);
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `slideToggle()` method.

```
$('li.dropdown-packages a').on('click', function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         e.stopPropagation();

var $packages = $('.custom-packages');

    $packages.slideToggle();

});
```

Comment: I used slideToggle also div is working but inside div dropdown link is not working...